# How Do I Get This CSS Transition Working?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

I have a CSS transition issue that doesn't appear to be working. Basically when the user scroll down a class is added to the header to set the "top" property to minus so it is hidden, and when the user scrolls back up the "top" property is set back to 0. However the transition to make it appear nice isn't working.

The development site can be found here - http://polarpc.co.uk/home/

If you inspect the header element, you'll see that I have the CSS property - transition: all 0.5s; on it.

I've tried also adding it to the class nav-up and nav-down which get added/removed when you scroll up/down but the same thing happens. I just want the header to appear that it's sliding up and down rather than just disappearing. Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

You have to give it an initial value for the browser to know how to animate the `top` property. Now it's going from an undefined value to -90px and the broswer doesn't how to do it gradually (undefined it not 0px). If you have `top: 0px` for the shown state and `top: -90px` for the hidden state it animates.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this top 0 and/or add transition: top .5s to the basic element. You need to tell the Browser where the positioning starts. In you case top: 0px

```
header.site-header {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    padding: 18px 40px !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    transition: top .5s;
    top: 0px;
}
```

You could also better use your specific by jquery generated classes

```
header.site-header {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    padding: 18px 40px !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-down {
    top: 0px;
    transition: top .5s;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -90px;
}
```